# XCode 6.1 iOS submission

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

I had updated my xcode to the latest version.
I wrote my program in swift and I try to upload it.
I put my Minimum System Version to 7.0 and added the SDK for 7.0 and it compiled fine.. but when I try to upload I get ERROR ITMS-90362 The value for key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle is invalid. the minimum value is 8.0.
I had double checked and I saw everywhere that swift supports iOS7. How is this possible?
Another problem is that I get this weird error: ERROR ITMS-90209 Invalid segment alignment. The app binary does not have the proper segment alignment.
I have the latest xcode from the AppStore. I even opened it through there. I tried extracting, clean, Application Loader.
Nothing seems to work.
I'm out of ideas.
Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "added the SDK for 7.0"?

Comment: In order to set the minimum SDK to 7 I needed to download the ios7 sdk

Comment: You do not have to download iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: But it does compile and run.without the sdk it cannot compile

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I got the exact same problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using embedded frameworks in your project?

If so, it could lead to such an error, as even though they work on iOS7, they're not supported on iOS7 and validation fails with a similar message when submitting.

Comment: I use parse.com only. I don't think it could hold me back

Answer (score 0):

If you're using swift features for ios8 only (e.g. transitions) then your program will still compile when your deployment target is ios7. You need to test it in the simulator with an ios7 device.

Comment: But I can run on a real ios7 device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the iOS 8 (or latest) SDK but set the "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 7.

Comment: I checked. The deployment it iOS 7. What is the difference between running on device and submitting?

Comment: Can you run with a release build or just the debug one? I have shipped an iOS 7 supporting Swift App to the store so I know it is definitely possible but I don't know the details of your project set up. Bundling frameworks is a blocker for iOS7 apps in the store. You may need to statically link the library and manually include the assets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error you had when trying to submit my app via xCode 6.1.1

Turns out, you can't mix Swift and dynamic libraries. I had 2 dynamics libraries in my project, and removing them and re-adding them another way (using cocoapods) fix my submission issue.